Please advise on asking a transgender question
OK, I'll be right up front. In right wing media it's no secret they don't buy in to the transgender theories, as they are popularly understood and discussed in other media. As such, right wing media regularly comment on it. The most recent iteration of this is the documentary "What is a woman?" made by right wing commentator Mark Walsh.
The documentary is largely Walsh interviewing transgender proponents, all leading to pivotal moments where he asks them "What is a woman?" Naturally, we can't expect a partisan documentary to allow opponents to look anything other than foolish, thus, as expected, the experts fumble the question, and can't seem to answer it. It's seemingly facetious when Walsh asks, yet in context it can become an honest question.
I'm asking for advice on how to ask that question here. With regards to certain definitions of gender, in context of transgender theory, what is a woman (and man, and "others")? My goal is first to understand what it means to "be a woman", because I truly don't get it, given the current definitions of other words. Secondly, I want to assure the community that my question is bona fide. Finally, I'm sure Walsh was unfair in his documentary portrayal of the other side. I'd like to offer a legitimate opportunity for response.
How can I ask this question?

Opinion-based questions tend to get closed here, so you would want to think about how to ask a question that can be answered with evidence instead.  Some questions about definitions are a better fit for english.SE or philosophy.SE, so you may want to think about why you would be asking this question here.  Questions are also better received when they reference background research, so taking a few minutes to search for the answer yourself would not only help compose an answerable question, but also improve the likelihood of it being accepted.

Some similar questions include https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/23461/14382 and https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/8803/14382 and https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/9737/14382

As @ArnonWeinberg pointed out in the comments, opinion-based questions tend to get closed here, and basing a question purely on Mark Walsh's documentary alone
This question as you put forward will likely be closed as opinion-based.
However...
If the question was to be laid out in such a manner similar to

Mark Walsh's documentary called What is a Woman? [Link provided], also covered in his book What Is a Woman?: One Man's Journey to Answer the Question of a Generation (Walsh, 2022), gives the right wing points of view by interviewing transgender proponents.
There is the argument that chromosomes or anatomy at birth determine gender identity, and from my research in context of transgender theory, a woman or man can be identified by other means [example links provided], and there are "others" who are non-binary in gender identity.
How are these arguments consolidated into a coherent argument in support of the transgender community (in argument against Mark Walsh)?
References
Walsh, M. (2022) What is a Woman?, also covered in his book What Is a Woman?: One Man's Journey to Answer the Question of a Generation DW Books ISBN:1956007008

As with the majority of accepted questions, the question may be left to stand on merit for the prior research you put in.
I think it is a difficult one with this question, as the answer (as far as I am aware at this point) may be seen as primarily based on opinion.  Again, as pointed out in the comments, you may want to think about why you would be asking this question here.  Are you looking for an answer from the psychology background, or biology? Or, are you more looking for a philosophical answer?  If you want a psychological based answer, then that needs to be clear in your question with the research links you provide or some other way in the question. If you are looking more for a biological or philosophical answer, https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/ or https://biology.stackexchange.com/ may be a better fit.

Thank you for the advise. I'm definitely looking for an answer based in psychology, since "transgenderism" as a theory is in the purview of psychologists.
